# Is there any identity for this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

While solving inequality and finite series problem I often come across this series-

$$(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)...(n+n)$$.

Is there a general solution to this form of a series?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Maybe $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$?

Comment: @menag A derivation...please...

Answer (score 3):

$\prod_{k = n + 1}^{2n} k = \frac{\prod_{k = n + 1}^{2n} k \prod_{k = 1}^{n} k}{\prod_{k = 1}^{n} k} = \frac{\prod_{k = 1}^{2n} k }{\prod_{k = 1}^{n} k} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!}$